# Help with this casting issue

Tags: c++

I'm making a game where pretty much everything inherits from Entity. I also have an IRenderable interface for all entities that need to be rendered.

When loading the level, every entity that is IRenderable is placed in a vector of IRenderable* which is then passed to the renderer.

When I instance any Entity, I add it to a vector of Entity* .

What I'm wondering is what exactly should I do when this entity sends an ENTITY_DESTROYED message?

The problem is that I do not know if this Entity is IRenderable. I'd have to try and cast it for that and I'm not sure if casting is a good idea here.

What else could I do to avoid casting?

Thanks

Another point to note, even if I know it is IRenderable, the pointer might be different due to multiple inheritance.

Comment: As a word of warning this kind of design scales poorly to 1000s of entities. A better idea is to have entities tell some renderer to render and do away with renderables as part of an inheritance hierarchy or component model, either by controlling data (e.g. creating/destroying renderables explicitly in entity code) or using "draw per call" methods. I have made the same mistake myself in my own game engine and would love to undo it... not to mention the cost of virtuals/inheritance if you want to run on anything other than a PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) is the best discussion which I've found on the subject.  I recommend it.

Otherwise, this may be useful.

```
class IRenderable;

class Entity {
public:
  virtual ~Entity() {}
  virtual IRenderable *getIRenderable() {return 0;}
}

class IRenderable : public Entity {
public:
  virtual IRenderable *getIRenderable() {return this;}
};
```

I'd call this solution a band-aid.

Comment: Even in the component based design how does it know the components associated to the Player to remove them?

Comment: Player probably should be the only one that knows which type of components it can provide, so you could have register/unregister methods.  When and by whom these are called is a hard question for me to answer.  *Usually*, you'd expect whatever controls ownership of Player to manage these calls.